# Android - Find Item By ID

Tags: java, android

Ok I have a very simple and yet difficult question.

I have 10 checkboxes, all called 'check', each one has a unique id from 1 - 10.
When I press a button on my app I want to be able to tell which checkboxes are checked and which aren't.

I'm sure the answer is very simple but I can't think of how I can do this.  I have the code for the button, I can't work out how to check each checkbox by id when they are all called 'check'.  Hopefully one of you guys can help me out.

Comment: Are the checkboxes explicitly created in the activity main layout, e.g. 10 checkboxes in the XML, or are they dynamically create, e.g. in a row layout that is used multiple times in a `ListView`?

Answer (score 16):

```
CheckBox chkbx1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.***);
chbkx1.isChecked();
```

isChecked() returns either true or false, based on the checked state of the checkbox.
hope that helps!

Answer (score 8):

try this,

in OnClickListener of your button add the following code

```
boolean checkedState[] = new boolean[10];

for(int i=0; i <= 10; i++) 
{
    CheckBox c = (CheckBox)findViewById(i);
    checkedState[i] = c.isChecked();
}
```

let me know what happened.

Comment: Indent all your code 4 spaces and it will apply code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Name the checkboxes differently from each other then use their id's. If you are using eclipse this should be really easy. Just open the xml file and modify the name there or use the visual and click on the checkbox and then modify the properties. Then just reference the checkboxes by their id.

Once you change the names, Brandon gives a great example of how to use the id and check if they are checked.